# Newton polygon : Show that precisely $ l$ of the $ \lambda_i$ are equal to $ \lambda$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

$\text{Newton Polygons for Polynomials}$

There is a lemma in the book $ \ \text{p-adic numbers, p-adic analysis and zet-functions} $ of the author $ \text{Neal Koblitz} \ $ which I mentioned below:

$ \text{Lemma 4}: \ $ Let $ f(X)=(1-\frac{X}{\alpha_1})(1-\frac{X}{\alpha_2}) \cdots (1-\frac{X}{\alpha_n})$ be the factorisation of $ f(X)$ in terms of its roots $ \alpha_i \in \Omega$. Let $ \lambda_i= \text{ord}_p (\frac{1}{\alpha_i})$. Then, if $ \lambda $ is a slope of the Newton polygon having length $l$, it follows that precisely $ l$ of the $ \lambda_i$ are equal to $ \lambda$.

($\Omega$ is a field which is the completion of the algebraic closure of the p-adic field $ \mathbb{Q}_p$)

In other words, the slopes of the Newton polygon of $f(X)$ are (counting multiplicity) the p-adic ordinals of the reciprocal roots of $f(X)$.

This is all about the Lemma.

**My question-**

Is the length $l$ of the Newton Polygon a natural number?

If it is true, then why?

According to the first statement of the Lemma, it says $ \text{precisely $l$ of the $ \lambda_i$ are equal to $ \lambda$}$, which imply $ l$ must be a natural number.

Though I could not explain it why it is a natural number or why should the length of the newton polygon be a natural number.

Please someone explain it.

Comment: Did you read in the book what the "length" of a segment of the Newton polygon means?  It does *not* mean the length of the segment in the usual sense, but its "horizontal length" (length of projection onto the $x$-axis).  Look up any other treatment of the Newton polygon and you should see something similar (e.g., the Wikipedia page on Newton polygons).

Comment: @KCd, what does  the sentence $ \text{precisely $ l$ of the $ \lambda_i$ are equal to $ \lambda$}$ mean here?

Comment: If in a list of numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ (not necessarily distinct) you're told that precisely 3 of the numbers are equal to 4/7 then are you not sure what that means?

Comment: @KCd, Is the horizontal length or the length of projection of the segment onto x-axis a natural number ?

Comment: Try looking at actual examples. For instance, Is the length of the projection of the line segment from (2,1/2) to (5,11/4) a natural number?

Comment: @KCd, In this case the projection vector has length $3$, which is a natural number.

Comment: @Kcd, Thank you very much. I got that the horizontal length is always a natural number in Newton polygon case